# Firebase Authentication Not Successful android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using to register user with email,name,address and password using Andrid Studio and Firebase.. As I click to register the user with Database It maynot Register Successfully and Go to the else Statement which is task not successful...

I have manually added login email over firebase but the scenrio is same the user did'n login...

I am confused and dont know What Did I do wrong... I am following tutorial and the same thing is done by the tutorial I am following...

Here is M Sigup...

```
public class AdminSignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textLogin;
Button btnSignup;
EditText AdminId,EmailAdmin,AdminName,AdminPassword,PhoneNO,Address;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference databaseAdminRegistration;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(AdminSignUp.this,MainActivity.class));
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_sign_up);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    textLogin=findViewById(R.id.txtLogin);
    btnSignup=findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdminSignUp);

    AdminId=findViewById(R.id.edtAdminId);
    EmailAdmin=findViewById(R.id.admiemail);
    AdminName=findViewById(R.id.edtAdminName);
    AdminPassword=findViewById(R.id.edtAdminPassword);
    PhoneNO=findViewById(R.id.edtAdminPhNo);
    Address=findViewById(R.id.edtAdminAddress);



    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FunRegisterAdmin();
           // Toast.makeText(AdminSignUp.this, "IN PROGRESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    textLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AdminSignUp.this,AdminLogin.class));
        }
    });
}

private void FunRegisterAdmin()
{
    String email = EmailAdmin.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String password = AdminPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name= AdminName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)|| !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        EmailAdmin.setError("Please Enter a Valid Email");
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)|| password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10){
        AdminPassword.setError("Enter The Password");
        return;
    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(name))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter NAme",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Employee");
                        reference.child(id).child("Name").setValue(name);
                        Toast.makeText(AdminSignUp.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {

                        Toast.makeText(AdminSignUp.this, "Not Registered...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
}
```

}

Here is My Login

```
public class AdminLogin extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView SignUPText;
EditText AdminEmail,AdminPassword;
Button AdminLoginBtn;

FirebaseAuth mAuth;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    startActivity(new Intent(AdminLogin.this,MainActivity.class));
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_login);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    SignUPText= findViewById(R.id.txtSignUp);
    AdminEmail= findViewById(R.id.edtEmailAdminLogin);
    AdminPassword= findViewById(R.id.edtPasswordAdminLogin);
    AdminLoginBtn=findViewById(R.id.ButtonAdminLogin);


    SignUPText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(AdminLogin.this,AdminSignUp.class));
        }
    });
    AdminLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AdminLoginFunc();
            //Toast.makeText(AdminLogin.this, "ADMIN LOGIN IN PROGRESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

private void AdminLoginFunc() {

    String email = AdminEmail.getText().toString().trim().toLowerCase();
    String password = AdminPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)|| !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        AdminEmail.setError("enter a valid email address");
        return;
    }
    if ((TextUtils.isEmpty(password)|| password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10)){
        AdminPassword.setError("enter a correct Password");
        return;
    }
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
    progressDialog.show();
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Toast.makeText(AdminLogin.this, "Login Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(AdminLogin.this, "Unable to Login.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //updateUI(null);
                    }
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

}
```

}

[image: Manually added users for signin but not working for signin]

Comment: Please post the exception

Answer (score 1):

You should try to log the value of the task result and see why it is failing.

Check out the value for

```
task.getException().getMessage()
task.getException().getErrorCode()
```

You can see the error codes here
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException

Also make sure that you have enabled the firebase user registration from the firebase auth admin dashboard.

Comment: it is executing the else condition on the Login and register...

Comment: Toast.makeText(AdminLogin.this, "Unable Login.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
it is executing this line in login and Signup Instead of Successful Login or SignUp

Comment: First we have to check if the signup is successful to do this open your firebase web admin dashboard and see if you can see registered users. 

Also in the signup try to toast / log the value of ```task.getException().getErrorCode()```

Comment: @KainatSyed If the signin task fails, it has an exception and error code that may help you figure out the cause of the failure. Logging this error code and message are the first step in troubleshooting the problem, as they typically explain what went wrong.

Comment: I have manually added users for checking the login but It is not working in Login also

Comment: In my code of Login and Register It is always executing the Else statement which contain the message the users is not able to login or signin

Comment: As multiple people trying to help you have said by now, you'll need to log the exception in the task. Without that we can't help further.